# If I undo code I wrote and don't type anything else in the ViewController, I get this response. Xcode Bug?

Tags: xcode, swift, error-handling, undo

[image]

As you can see, I'm not referencing a delegate or a function called hideButton(). I haven't gone past cleaning and trying to recompile the project, but even doing that I am still getting the false error.

After this, I just created a new line below the print statement and the code compiled correctly. Is this a bug with Xcode, or an intended "too complicated to bother fixing" issue?

Comment: There's been a few bugs where single-line closures (where the type signature of the closure is left out) yields weird non-related errors. Try adding a type signature to the closure, e.g. `..., completion: { () -> () in print("dismissed to map") })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bug. Try cleaning Xcode, quitting it and opening it. If it still is weird then just keep the line below because functionality is more important than how code looks.